# No OpenID buttons for unregistered users when answering questions

Tags: feature-request, usability, login, new-users

If an unregistered user goes to answer a question, they have the option of OpenID login, but there are no easy OpenID buttons (like the "Google" and "Yahoo" buttons on the login screen).

http://img651.imageshack.us/img651/7075/noopenidbuttons.png

Answer (score 1):

I have that problem when I try to login from my blackberry, very frustrating.